# C# Winnovative HTML to PDF

Tags: c#, winnovative

I am searching for a solution to convert HTML to PDF with external CSS support. I downloaded the trial version of the Winnovative Toolkit Total v11.14, and tried out the demo application for the method public byte[] GetPdfBytesFromHtmlString (string htmlString, string urlBase). The PDF files are generated, but the CSS is not applied.

Note: I tried the same input HTML string and base URL in the demo site. It's working fine, so I don't know why it's not working in my system. The demo application is shared in v11.14 ZIP files.

Input provided for this method:

- htmlString = HTML source of the url 'http://www.winnovative-software.com/'
- urlBase = "http://www.winnovative-software.com/"

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: How did you solved your issue. Please update your post with the things that worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any proxy to access Internet? In this case you should set the HtmlToPdfConverter.ProxyOptions object properties in your code.